# Unable to disable hibernate on Windows Server 2008 using - powercfg /h off?

Tags: windows-server-2008, hibernation

I'm confused as of why I am still unable to disable the Hibernate feature to save space (due to Hiberfil.sys is as big as the RAM) ?

Using the DOMAIN\Administrator login,I have followed the steps: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/920730 and then followed by restart but then it is still exist ?

FYI: this is on Windows Server 2008 Standard Edition x64 with 4 GB RAM and some 4GB+

any help and suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've always found the hibernate setting a little flaky. Here's how I disable it:

powercfg.exe -h on

powercfg.exe -h off

For some reason, enabling it (even if it's already enabled) and then disabling it seems to work.

Comment: many thanks for the answer Joe, yes you are right, the file then can be deleted manually if it is necessary.

Comment: Glad to help...